# JS Function to change title of html div based on the textContent

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to have js change the title attributes for each div based on each divs text content in html.

I want to add the title of each div from its own text, so for example: "Text Example 1"s title would be "Text Example 1", "Text Example 2"s title would be "Text Example 2" and so on.

Currently I've made a js code that does that but only for one of the divs. I'm a complete beginner in js so any advice is appreciated.

```html
<div class="example">
<div class="text1" id="id-text1">Text Example 1</div>
</div>

<div class="example">
<div class="text1" id="id-text1">Text Example 2</div>
</div>

<div class="example">
<div class="text1" id="id-text1">Text Example 3</div>
</div>
```

```js
const titleContent = document.getElementById("id-text1");

function ChangeTitle(){
document.querySelectorAll('.text1').forEach(function ChangeTitleSecond(){
titleContent.setAttribute('title', titleContent.textContent);
})
};

window.onload = ChangeTitle();
```

Comment: getElementById() returns only a single element.  id attributes should be unique within the document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Steps to set title of `<div>` to it's (text) content:

1. Get all of the `<div>`s (selector is `div.text1`)
2. For each of them, set title to `innerText` value

Solution:

```html
<div class="example">
  <div class="text1">Text Example 1</div>
</div>
<div class="example">
  <div class="text1">Text Example 2</div>
</div>
<div class="example">
  <div class="text1">Text Example 3</div>
</div>
<script>
divs = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("div.text1"))

for (elem of divs) {
  elem.setAttribute("title", elem.innerText)
}
</script>
```

[Demo](https://better-bored.rixthetyrunt.repl.co/?html=%3Cdiv%20class%3D%22example%22%3E%0A%20%20%3Cdiv%20class%3D%22text1%22%3EText%20Example%201%3C%2Fdiv%3E%0A%3C%2Fdiv%3E%0A%3Cdiv%20class%3D%22example%22%3E%0A%20%20%3Cdiv%20class%3D%22text1%22%3EText%20Example%202%3C%2Fdiv%3E%0A%3C%2Fdiv%3E%0A%3Cdiv%20class%3D%22example%22%3E%0A%20%20%3Cdiv%20class%3D%22text1%22%3EText%20Example%203%3C%2Fdiv%3E%0A%3C%2Fdiv%3E%0A%3Cscript%3E%0Adivs%20%3D%20Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(%22div.text1%22))%0A%0Afor%20(elem%20of%20divs)%20%7B%0A%20%20elem.setAttribute(%22title%22%2C%20elem.innerText)%0A%7D%0A%3C%2Fscript%3E)

Comment: Changed it up a bit to just target `.text1` classes instead of `div.example`, but it works perfectly. Thank you.

Comment: That's what I did, I made the selectors `div.text1`... :)

Answer (score 1):

getElementById() returns only a single element. id attributes should be unique within the document.  But that's ok, you don't need it.  You're already getting a list of the elements to go through with querySelectorAll()

forEach() will pass each element as the first parameter of your function.

```
function ChangeTitle(){
 document.querySelectorAll('.text1').forEach(function 
  ChangeTitleSecond(item){
   item.setAttribute('title', item.textContent);
  })
};

window.onload = ChangeTitle();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this implementation. If you need a list of some items which has the same attributes (such as id, class or tag) you can pick them all through their specific attribute of them by querySelectorAll.

```
const titleContentList = document.querySelectorAll('[id=id-text1]')

function ChangeTitle(){

titleContentList.forEach((item)=>{
const title = item.textContent

if(!title) return;

item.setAttribute('title',title)
})                   
  } 

window.onload = ChangeTitle();
```